# JavaScript audio elements on IE and Windows Server 2012

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, audio, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to run a web application on Windows Server 2012 R2 (running on Azure) via IE11 but what I'm getting is a JavaScript error

[image]

Application was tested prior on Windows 7 with IE11 and I never experienced that error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Server versions of windows/IE11 run in an enhanced security mode. Also on your server instance, websites in ISS are mapped to the intranet zone (File>Properties menu) where the "display intranet sites in compatibility view" may force the site into IE7 Emulation. (f12>Emulation tab will tell you which emulation mode is being used and how it was applied) I expect you will see on the server IE11 as IE7 - display intranet sites in compatibility view. Use a windows client running IE11 to test your websites hosted on an external or internal host.

Comment: @RobParsons that web app is served by Apache Linux  server but then is loaded inside windows application in the Windows Server so is nothing to do with ISS rather how JavaScript is handled (Audio element in this case) on Windows Server